# <system.webServer> <modules...> works in Web.Base.config, but not in Web.Debug/Release.Config

Tags: web-config, global-asax

Simple problem. Breakpoint in MyModule.cs code is hit when I put the snippet below into Web.Base.config, but not when I put it into Web.Debug.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="MyModule" type="MyNamespace.MyModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This is what I have in the csproj file

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" StackTrace="true" />
</Target>
```

So the problems seems to be that Web.Base.config and Web.$(Configuration).config are not getting properly combined into a generated Web.config

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm just being stupid. There is no default transform. In order for it to work I needed to specify xdt:Transform on a corresponding line

```
<add name="MyModule" type="MyNamespace.MyModule" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
```